# Hibernate inserting null for OrderColumn value

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following collection defined in one of my entities:

```java
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
@Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@OrderColumn(name = "pos")
public Set<Role> roles;
```

But when I try save an entity, Hibernate tries to insert "null" into the "pos" column, which fails, as it has a non-null constraint. (Edit: If I remove the non-null constraint, it inserts null into every row.)

Why wouldn't Hibernate populate the order column?

Comment: AFAIR, it starts by inserting null, and then updates the rows to set their order.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried removing the non-null constraint, but then it just left them all as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `OrderColumn` on a Set which is not an Ordered collection. I doubt that could be the problem.

You can change it to List from Set and try.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. Since the underlying Set was a LinkedHashSet, I though this wouldn't be a problem, since it has an order, but I guess it needs to be an actual List.